# IPv4 "in subnet" function

Tags: javascript

Implement the following JavaScript method as short as possible:

```
function same_subnet(ip_a,ip_b,sn_mask)
{

}
```

It should get 2 IP addresses and a subnet mask. It should return `true` if `ip_a` and `ip_b` are in the same subnet.

Example calls:

1. `same_subnet("192.168.0.1","192.168.0.15","255.255.255.0")` → `true`
2. `same_subnet("192.168.0.1","192.168.1.15","255.255.0.0")` → `true`
3. `same_subnet("192.168.0.1","192.168.1.15","255.255.255.0")` → `false`

Comment: Could it be any language or just javascript? If just javascript, please add javascript tag!

Comment: In other words, implement the isInNet function as used in Proxy Auto-Config (PAC) files, but under a different name, and only accepting an IPv4 address as the "host".

Answer (score 1):

## 126

Fits into a tweet and doesn't even leak globals.

```
function same_subnet(a,b,c){function x(n){return n=n.split("."),n[0]<<24|n[1]<<16|n[2]<<8|n[3]}return(x(a)&x(c))==(x(b)&x(c))}
```

Comment: Looks to me like it leaks the global `x`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Try again ;-)

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood or misremembered Crockford's book.